# Order received mail in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a shopping cart in wordpress that is used for payments, At the last it generate the page with thanks message and some information that user entered at the time of shopping. I just want to build the functionality that user can be send(email) that information to his xyz friend.

Answer (score 0):

Add hidden fields and create a form in html, pass that values on onSubmit event.

use WP_main function to send email.

Comment: Is this WP_main or WP_mail ?